# Searching for and deleting an event in Google Apps Script

Tags: function, google-apps-script, calendar

I've created a pre-booking form for people visiting site which captures a user's input and is placed into a google sheet. An approver subsequently sets the approval status in the sheet and an email is sent with the approval status and the details.

What I am trying to achieve is upon rejection of a site visit, to search for the event in the calendar and delete it!

```
function deleteFromCalendar(row_values)
{
var startDate = row_values[4]; //Event Start Date
var nameAndCompany = row_values[2]; //Name and Company
var approval = row_values[16]; //Approval Status
  
  
//if the visit has been rejected, search the calendar for the matching start date and person and delete the event from the calendar  
if  (approval == 'Rejected'){
var events2 = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('arbritrary calendar address goes here').getEventsForDay(startDate, {search: nameAndCompany});
CalendarApp.deleteEvent(events2);
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction as the correct way to return the event and delete it?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hi, was your issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove and event via Apps Script, you just have to use [CalendarEvent.deleteEvent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#deleteEvent()).

Since [getEventsForDay](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#geteventsfordaydate,-options) returns an array of `CalendarEvents`, you should iterate through this array and delete the corresponding events. You should just replace this:

```js
CalendarApp.deleteEvent(events2);
```

With this:

```js
events2.forEach(event => event.deleteEvent());
```

#### Reference:

- [CalendarEvent.deleteEvent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar-event#deleteEvent())